# Javascript doesn't work for input validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have seen many different ways to do it, and any of them works me.

I am using bootstrap.

The form goes directly to the 'action' (I want to validate first on 'onupdate')

SCRIPT:

```
[...]
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css/">

<script type="text/javascript">
        function valForm() 
        {
            alert("HALOOOOOOOOO");
            var errors = 0;
            var title = document.forms["tutorial_form"]["title"].value;
            var description = document.forms["tutorial_form"]["description"].value;
            var url = document.forms["tutorial_form"]["url"].value;

            if (title == null || title == "") 
            {
                document.getElementById("title_div").style.class = "form-group has-warning";
                errors++;
            }
            if (description == null || description == "") 
            {
                document.getElementById("description_div").style.class = "form-group has-warning";
                errors++;
            }
            if (url == null || url == "") 
            {
                document.getElementById("url_div").style.class = "form-group has-warning";
                errors++;
            }
            if( errors > 0)
            {
                document.getElementById("error_container").innerHTML = "<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p><b>ERROR!</b>All the information must be fulfilled.</p></div>";
                return false;
            }

        }
    </script>
</head>
```

FORM:

```
<div class="container">
    <form name="tutorial_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="insert_tutorial.php" onsubmit="return valForm()" method="post">
        <div id="title_div" class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Title input">
        </div>
        <div id="description_div" class="form-group">
            <label for="description">Description</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Description" rows="5"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="url_div" class="form-group">
            <label for="url">Video URL</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="url" name="url" placeholder="Insert youtube url">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="file">Insert image file</label>
            <input type="file" name="image" id="file">
            <p class="help-block">Select the file. Take care that it's size is no longer that 16 MB.</p>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">
    </form>
    <hr>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: I think you need event.preventDefault(); to stop the form from submitting.

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the browser console? Your code looks like it has syntax errors to me.

Comment: To assign a CSS class to an element you would have to use `Element.className = ...` and not `Element.style.class = ...`

Comment: Thank u, now it works. Thanks for all, I have many errors. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your last if statement, change the double quotes to  single ones:

```
document.getElementById("error_container").innerHTML = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'><p><b>ERROR!</b>All the information must be fulfilled.</p></div>";
```

or you can escape them as well:

```
"<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\"><p><b>ERROR!</b>All the information must be fulfilled.</p></div>";
```